# finding parameter's values in PDF using median point

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X be a continuous random variable, with PDF  $$ \begin{equation}
  f_X(x) =\begin{cases}
    0, & \text{ $x<20$}\\
    a, & \text{ $20 \le x<25$}\\
    \frac{1}{15}, & \text{ $25 \le x<30$}\\
    b, & \text{ $30 \le x<35$}\\
    c, & \text{ $35 \le x$}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}$$
It is known that $$P\{X \le 30 \} = P\{X \ge 30 \}$$
I need to find the values of a, b and c.

From the given info that 30 is the median I know that $$\frac{1}{2} = P\{X \le 30 \} = \int_{20}^{25}adx + \int_{25}^{30}\frac{dx}{15}=5a + \frac{1}{3}\Longrightarrow a = \frac{1}{30}$$
But I don't know how to find b & c. I instinctively want to say that $c = 0$ because $$1 = \int_{20}^{25}adx + \int_{25}^{30}\frac{1}{15}dx + \int_{30}^{35}bdx +\int_{35}^{\infty}cdx$$ and $\int_{35}^{\infty}cdx$ doesn't converge for any $c\in \mathbb{R}$ and then $$\int_{30}^{35}bdx = \frac{1}{2}\Longrightarrow b = \frac{1}{10}$$ but I'm not sure that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the density is piecewise constant, all we need to do is compute the relevant areas under each interval.  You are correct that $c = 0$.  We then have $$(25 - 20)a + (30 - 25)\tfrac{1}{15} + (35 - 30)b = 1,$$ and $$(35 - 30)b = \tfrac{1}{2}.$$  This gives $b = \frac{1}{10}$ and $a = \frac{1}{30}$.